# SELECT WHERE date is 5 days before the maximum date in SQLITE

Tags: sqlite

How do I select rows where the date is 5 days before the maximum date?

I used the following code, which is not raising any errors, but is still not working:

```
SELECT ProductId FROM kPRODUCTS where dateCreated > date('MAX(dateCreated)','-5 days');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't that be:

```
SELECT ProductId FROM kPRODUCTS where dateCreated > date((SELECT MAX(dateCreated) FROM kPRODUCTS),'-5 days');
```

(Use a subselect and watch your quotes).